# Navbar always fixed, although it’s meant to be conditional

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I would like to have two states on a navbar. One, in which the navbar is always fixed(this is when the screen width is below 766) and another, where the nav should appear and be fixed when scrolling down a bit.

I also tried adding a sticky and fixed position in CSS when the screen gets smaller, but it doesn’t work.

Both of these work independently, but if I combine them in an if condition, it’s either always one, or the other working and overwriting the other one, depending on the order I have the function and the other code using the function.

I am not very experienced in JavaScript and not sure what consequences it has in this case to have a function declared only in the scope of an if. When declaring it outside of the if condition, it doesn’t work either.

Here’s my JavaScript code:

```
if ($(window).width() < 766) {
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
} else {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
  };

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-500px";
    }
  }
}
```

The navbar is made with bootstrap:

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar navbar-expand-lg" id="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/Logo.jpg" style="margin-right: 40px; width: 250px; height: auto;" alt="LOGO"/></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a " class="nav-item nav-link active" style="margin-right: 40px; font-size: 18px;" href="index.html">Projekte <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="margin-right: 40px; font-size: 18px;" href="lineofactivity.html">Tätigkeitsfelder</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="margin-right: 40px; font-size: 18px;" href="contactteam.html">Kontakt/Team</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" style="font-size: 18px;" href="impressum.html">Impressum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: This might be worth giving a read: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: If your window width is small when loading the page, `.onscroll` handler will not be registered. Is this what you want? What if users resize the browser window on desktop? A window resize handler might help as well. You are using mixed jQuery and JavaScript. Do you want to add a jquery tag then?

Comment: Please also share the HTML and CSS, ideally in an interactive snippet, so that we can reproduce your issue. For example, you speak of `sticky`, while it’s more likely that you mean the CSS value `fixed`.

Comment: i shared the html, theres no CSS since its made with bootstrap. And yes, I meant fixed